# Scala: Using span with modular arithmetic

Tags: scala, math, modular

I have a `List[Int]` from 1 to 10 and want to make a `List[List[Int]]` containing two `List[Int]`: one list containing even numbers and the other containing odd numbers. The result should be like this:

```
List(List(2,4,6,8,10),List(1,3,5,7,9))
```

I tried these things:

```
1.to(10).toList.span((x:Int) => x % 2 == 0)
```

and

```
val lst = 1.to(10).toList; lst span (_%2==0)
```

However, neither of these worked.

Can someone help me on this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you need to use is `partition`, not `span`:

```
scala> (1 to 10).partition(_ % 2 == 0)
res0: (IndexedSeq[Int], IndexedSeq[Int]) = (Vector(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),Vector(1, 3, 5, 7, 9))
```

Since you want a `List[List[Int]]`, you could do this:

```
val lst = (1 to 10).toList
val (evens, odds) = lst.partition(_ % 2 == 0)
val newList = List(evens,odds) // List(List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10), List(1, 3, 5, 7, 9))
```

The `span` method can only be used to split a sequence at a single point:

```
scala> (1 to 10).span(_ < 5)
res1: (Range, Range) = (Range(1, 2, 3, 4),Range(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

When you tried `lst.span(_ % 2 == 0)`, the program found that the first item, 1, did not pass the test (`_ % 2 == 0`), so all the elements were put in the second list, leaving none in the first.

Comment: I misunderstood the way span() works. Thank you for your brief and clear explanation :)